# Conditional statement not going as planned with None type in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This script is inserting 'NULL' values in a table depending on the date.
But there is another table that contains 'NULL' values depending on if it has been sent or not. Which in this case it has not been sent so I want to ignore them. But the code continues on and gives me this traceback:

The Traceback is as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\projects\docs\script.py", line 43, in <module>
     if dr3 < date_sql[0] < dt:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'
```

Been strugling for a long time, so really appreciate your guidance as I have tried to find a solution.

Python code is:

```
import pyodbc
from datetime import date, datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

conn = pyodbc.connect(
r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
r'SERVER=server;'
r'DATABASE=db;'
)

dt = datetime.today()
dr3 = dt - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=3)

cursor = conn.cursor()

sent_date = cursor.execute("""SELECT sent_date, id
              FROM Department.Documents""")


def fetch_date():
   for row in sent_date:
       r = row
   return r


date_sql = fetch_date()


if sent_date != None:
   if dr3 < date_sql[0] < dt:
      try:
         value = None
         cursor.execute("""UPDATE Department.Customer SET name=?, address=?, email=?, 
                      phone=?""", (value, value, value, value))

         cursor.commit()

      except pyodbc.Error as ex:
         print(str(ex))

         cursor.rollback()

else:
  cursor.close()
  print("Connection closed")
```

Comment: Would it make sense to just exclude null dates in your query?  `SELECT sent_date, id FROM Department.Documents WHERE sent_date IS NOT NULL`

Comment: `fetch_date()` is just returning the date from the last row returned by the query. But you haven't used `ORDER BY`, so the order of rows is unpredictable. This makes little sense. If you want a specific row, you should use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: You can also do the date comparison in SQL: `WHERE sent_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)`. This will also automatically filter out null dates.

Comment: The `UPDATE` query is updating *all* rows of the table, since it has no `WHERE` clause. Is that really what you want?

Comment: You should do the `if sent_date is not None:` test before calling `fetch_date()`, otherwise it will get an error when it tries to loop over it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, forget to mention that, I want to fetch all the dates and not only the last one. For the update, I want the `UPDATE` query to update all the rows, yes.